# Android when users do not use Chrome does not deep link properly

Tags: android, android-deep-link

I found that on Android 12 if your default browser is Samsung or Firefox that Android app links do not open in app and it appears to be on purpose.

See links on how to turn it off on your device
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/set-firefox-android-open-links-native-apps
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AeMz-sNCJ3s

This is problematic for our use-case where we do not have web equivalent of those pages.  We are using Android app links to just link into the app directly to a page.

I can not find an optimal solution here.  Below are some thoughts

1. Have the android app link go to the custom schema but that will not work well if they do not have the app installed
2. So naturally you would consider doing firebase dynamic links but they do not support custom schemas.  The URL must be http or https
3. So I would likely need to use a more advanced solution which is like branch.io

I would prefer to use firebase dynamic links but it appears to not support what I want.  Anyone have any other suggestions?